# angular material referring a constant in the html file

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material2

I have defined my constants like below

**constants.ts**

```
  export const Constant = Object.freeze({
       ACCEPTED_LEADS_TO_CALL: "Accepted Leads to Call",
       RECOMMENDED_CALL_LIST: "Recommended Call List"
     });
```

This is very convenient to refer in .ts files like

```
import { Constant } from '../constants'

var str = Constant.RECOMMENDED_CALL_LIST
```

But how do i refer it in the .html of the component?

**my-component.html**

```
<div>name: {{Constant.RECOMMENDED_CALL_LIST}}</div>
```

fails with compile time errors as it cannot resolve Constant.

Comment: How about using a string enum instead of const

Comment: create a property in your component and bind it in the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to your constants into your component

```
export class MyComponent {
  constants = Constant;
  ...
}
```

You can then use it in your template :

```
<p>{{ constants.RECOMMENDED_CALL_LIST }}</p>
```